# Busca em tuplas com Python e Mysql

Tags: mysql, python

Olá, Boa Noite!!!
Sou novato na programação Python, e recentemente recebi um trabalho na faculdade de implementar um programa similar ao akinator, utilizando a linguagem desejada, por ter mais facilidade, resolvi utilizar o Python. A ideia é fazer perguntas ao usuário, e retornar apenas um valor com base nas respostas obtidas. Fiz isso em um banco teste mysql, de forma estática, com perguntas "chumbadas" no código, e um select ao final utilizando todos os parâmetros. Porém, este método ficará muito trabalhoso para criar o banco e para o usuário responder, pois teria que responder 50 questões para que o resultado seja único. Pensei então em fazer uma tabela de perguntas e uma de resultados. Minha ideia é apresentar perguntas aleatórias e utilizar um id na pergunta para realizar o select.
Exemplo:
- O carro é da marca Fiat?
De acordo com a resposta, gostaria de fazer um select, armazenando os resultados que satisfaçam a condição, e após isso realizar uma nova pergunta aplicando novo select apenas nestes valores já filtrados. Com isso acredito que o número de perguntas ficaria menor, e as mesmas poderiam ser feita de forma aleatória (um dos requisitos do professor). Porém, não faço ideia de como aplicar isso na prática, ou seja, como armazenar os resultados em algum lugar, e realizar o novo select apenas nestes valores armazenados. Esse laço seria realizado até que o resultado apresentado seja = 1. Poderiam me ajudar? Segue o que havia feito até agora.

```
import pymysql

con = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'python')

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
    version = cur.fetchone()
    print("Database version: {}".format(version[0]))

print("Ola eu sou o adivinhator!!!")
print("Pense em alguma coisa e eu vou adivinhar!!!")
print("Responda as perguntas utilizando 's' para SIM e 'n' para NÃO seguido da tecla ENTER!!!")
comecar = input("Podemos começar?\n")
if comecar == "S":
    print("La vai a primeira pergunta")
else:
    print("esperando voce")
vmarca = input("O carro e da marca FIAT?\n")
vportas = input("O carro tem 2 portas?\n")
vpotencia = input("O carro é 1.0?\n")
vtipo = input("O carro é utilitário?\n")
vtipo2 = input("O carro é hatch?\n")
qry_p = ("SELECT nome  FROM resultados where fiat = '"+vmarca+"'AND 2portas='"+vportas+"'AND pot='"+vpotencia+"'AND utilitario='"+vtipo+"'AND hatch='"+vtipo2+"'")
cur.execute(qry_p)
result = cur.fetchone()
print("O carro que pensou é", result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode armazenar os id's das linhas após cada resposta e usar isso como condição na próxima pergunta com `WHERE id IN (id1, id2, id3,...,idn)`. Vai perguntando até a lista de id's ter somente 1 elemento.

Comment: No seu exemplo, eu armazenaria os ID dos resultados, com base no select é isso? A minha principal dúvida neste caso, seria como armazenar esta tupla/lista de ID e depois realizar o próximo select apenas nestes valores armazenados, conseguiria me dar um exemplo?